# Quit R session in RStudio without leaving RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

This is a strange request - but is it possible to 1) terminate an R session from within RStudio but keep RStudio open?  ... and then 2) to start a new R session from within RStudio?

I see such a feature [was requested](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200667607-Elegant-way-to-quit-restart-the-R-session) of RStudio in 2013 but I don't know if it is implemented.

Comment: You can restart R in rstudio by entering `.rs.restartR`

Comment: This does not appear to wipe the environment in RStudio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rstudio (at least on Windows version 3.3.0), in the top menu bar with file, edit etc. under ***Session*** is an option to ***Terminate R...*** which will terminate the R session but RStudio will stay open and automatically restart a new R session.

Comment: thanks! Those toolbar menus! I should look at those more!